# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Override the initial command 'npm start' to 'pnpm start'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

Previous EB UI provide a 'Command Box' to allow us override the initial command.
But now the new UI I just cannot find this field anywhere.

I am using NodeJS EB platform.

Or is there any way to run the pnpm start instead of npm start through the .ebextension?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Procfile` in root directory with content:

```
web: pnpm start
```

See also [official documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-configuration-procfile.html)